# Preventing a plugin from remapping a key in vim

Tags: vi, vim, macvim, vim-plugin

I have a bunch of plugins installed for vim, and one of them is breaking the `dw` command. I'm not sure which one it is though. Basically `dw` is now deleting everything up through the next bit of whitespace it finds, instead of stopping at punctuation like it should.

I really don't want to have to figure out which one is breaking it and how to fix it. Is there a way I can specify in my .vimrc that I don't want it changed?

**Edit:**

Luc already answered my question, but I thought I would still clear it up for future readers, because there is a bit of disagreement over what `dw` is supposed to do by default. Lets say we have the word 1234.5678. By default, on all the systems I've worked on, if the cursor is on the 1, typing `dw` should leave you with .5678. When I asked the question, typing dw for me was instead deleting the whole thing (1234.5678).

Comment: You are looking for `de`. `d` for delete followed by the motion `e` which goes to the end of a `word`. You can use `E` for end of `WORD`. For more help: `:h word-motions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are looking for the right thing. Search instead which (ft?) plugin is overriding `'isk'` -- still with verbose -> `:verbose set isk`

```
:h w 
:h word
```

Comment: And yet, it was you that gave me the idea ;) As `dw` is command + motion, it's unlikely to be mapped. Well it may happen, but I've never seen it. Unlike `&isk` that gave me headaches with some filetype.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I found a place where isk was being overridden, deleted the line and now it's all good.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>dw</kbd> isn't a mapping. <kbd>d</kbd> is a command that accepts a [motion](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html) and the correct behaviour is exactly the one described by you. <kbd>dw</kbd> stands for delete word and does that :). By the way, if you want to know something about you mappings I suggest you to try the following commands:

```
:map
```

that gives you the list of all your mappings. And the wonderful:

```
:verbose map <c-s>
```

that gives you details about the given mapping ( in our case `<c-s>`)

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is not in 'iskeyword' option mentioned by @Luc Hermitte, then there are two possibilites:

1. Normal-mode mapping that remaps `d` or `dw`. Command to check whether it is the problem:

   ```
   verbose nmap d
   ```

   . It will report all `d*` mappings, including `d` itself and `dw`. I do not think there will be many.
2. Operator-pending mapping that remaps `w`. Check using

   ```
   verbose omap w
   ```

I don't think though that any plugin author is arrogant enough to remap this, so first check @Luc Hermitte's answer.